# Azure AD B2C Configuration URL cannot be reached

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I configured a new Azure AD B2C Tenant for testing purposes. I am trying to follow the example to use Azure AD B2C with Android.

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-android-native-appauth

I created beside the B2C Tenant already a User Flow for the login.

During the authentication flow the app wants to read the "well known openid configuration" for my User Flow

https://login.microsoftonline.com/geomobilestage.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration?p=B2C_1_login_signin

but the URL returns a 404 error. But when I try the following URL to read the configuration I receive http status 200

https://geomobilestage.b2clogin.com/geomobilestage.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_login_signin/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration

The URLs are public so everyone can try to call them in the browser to see the result.

So the configuration itself exists and seems to be ok. I have already another Azure AD B2C tenant and when I try to call the first URL for this tenant everything is fine. It seems to be that I am missing some configuration in the Azure portal but I really have no idea what I am missing and even where to look.

Regards

Michael

Answer (score 2):

For Azure AD, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-protocols-oidc#fetch-the-openid-connect-metadata-document):

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration`

For Azure AD B2C, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/openid-connect#validate-the-id-token):

`https://{domain-name}.b2clogin.com/{domain-name}.onmicrosoft.com/{policy}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration`

The key thing here is to realize that the b2c config endpoint has a reference to a **policy** in it, otherwise it’s likely AAD.

Comment: well, can you please take a look at the URLs I provided. Both URLs contains the policy B2C_1_login_signin. This should not be the problem

Comment: If you add both tenant and policy to the first URL, it will return 404. Otherwise, the second URL is used for Azure AD B2C. I tried the first one with my b2c tenant(and AD tenant) and policy, it returned 404. Please provide more details about your *another Azure AD B2C tenant*.

Comment: Hi @MichaelMeyer. It's recommended that you don't refer to the login.microsoftonline.com domain for an Azure AD B2C tenant since this will be deprecated on 14 January 2021. For more information, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/b2clogin#deprecation-of-loginmicrosoftonlinecom.